# AngularJS: applying event listener to multiple elements

Tags: angularjs

I need to add / remove certain classes based on a click on any of the multiple elements (element children). These elements can be constructed dynamically on page load so I can't put ng-click on each.

How can I accomplish this correctly and as easily in AngularJS ?

```
$(".btn-group > .btn").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

addClass(), siblings() and removeClass() should work without having jQuery included as far as I know since Angular has its jqLite right?

I am sure I am missing something obvious ...
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More elegantly you could extend the .btn class like this :

```
.directive('btn', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'C' // call the directive on DOM elements with the class 'btn'
      link: function( scope, elem, attr ){
        if( elem.parent().hasClass('btn-group'){
          elem.bind( 'click', function(){
            elem.parent().children().removeClass('active');
            elem.addClass('active');
          });
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Any .btn on your dom will then have the custom behavior if it has been correctly compiled.

Answer (score 0):

You could use event delegation.

Basically you will need to add an event listner to the parent element of the dynamically created elements and check the source of the event bubble up

```
document.querySelector('input[type="button"]').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var el = document.createElement('li');
  var id = new Date().getTime().toString();
  el.id = id;
  el.innerHTML = id;
  document.querySelector('.ct').appendChild(el);
});

document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'li') {
    alert(event.target.id);
  }
});
```

please refer to this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/founddrama/ggMUn/)